# How can I get the user's Facebook profile link with verification?

Tags: react-native, facebook, react-native-fbsdk

In my app, user can add their Facebook profile link. But I don't want to add the user's Facebook profile link without verifying it.

I can get the user's verified Facebook profile link from `LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["user_link"]` using `react-native-fbsdk-next` package. But I don't want to log in using Facebook since the user already signed in using google or any other way in my app.

Comment: Having the user Login is of course the only way for them to verify that they are them. How else would they verify that they are them?

Comment: Yes. Exactly said. Users must have to sign in Facebook to verify them. But not to my app. LoginManager.logInWithPermissions means it's logging into my app also.

Comment: They must login to your app, otherwise your app can't get any information about them to begin with.

Comment: But you won't be able to get their _actual_ profile URL via API, that is not possible any more. All the `link` field of the user object gives you is a tokenized link, that will only work for people who are friends with the user.